# .hhc/.hhk converting to browser viewable HTML

Tags: chm

I had a help file in the .chm format (mirc.chm) and I wanted to make an online version of it. I knew it contained .html files so I decompiled it to get the separate files. Everything can be viewed fine in a web browser except for the table of contents file which is in the .hhc format (mirc.hhc) and the index file, which is in the .hhk format (mirc.hhk).

Does anyone know of any scripts/programs to convert the mentioned files to valid .html files so that I don't have to create my own index/table of content files?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found something that might work for you. Here's a link to it: http://forum.isilo.com/showthread.php?t=165. A quick description from the forum post:

> I've created a utility called hhc2html
>   which converts an HTML help .hhc file
>   to a set of HTML pages.

Comment: Thanks for the tool.There is a small bug/ unexpected behavior in the above tool.The TOC are created but it is missing the logic to consolidate the Topic names or to create sub topics to one if many topics have the same name.